# How to use arrowkeys to scroll through images in a folder with picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I'm in the process of creating a pretty simple image viewer.

I've got a Picturebox control to display the image. And I'd like to be able to use the arrow keys to scroll through all of the images in a folder - basically, the way the default Windows picture viewer does. At the moment, I have an Open File Dialog to choose the image to display, but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Pretty new to programming, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the KeyPress Event, you can get the information about the pressed key in its KeyPressEventArgs.